# Javascript regex negation give the incorrect result

Tags: javascript, regex

For example my data like this

```
AAAG        ( 382 TO 385 )( 1729 TO 1732 )( 2405 TO 2408 )( 3759 TO 3762 )
AAAKSKSAL       ( 1941 TO 1949 )( 3973 TO 3981 ) AAAKSKSAL
```

I tried below script

```
var xa = "AAAKSKSAL     ( 1941 TO 1949 )( 3973 TO 3981 )";
var regex = /([^\dTO\s\(\)]+)/g;
var matches =  [];
matches = regex.exec(xa); 
alert(matches);
```

My string contain only one data but it alerts `AAAKSKSAL,AAAKSKSAL`.

Or Else

```
var xa = "AAAKSKSAL    ( 1941 TO 1949 )( 3973 TO 3981 ) ( 1941 TO 1949 )( 3973 TO 3981 ) AAAKSKSAL AAAKSKSAL AAAKSKSAL";
```

It alerts `AAAKSKSAL,AAAKSKSAL`. But in previous example my input data contain four matched elements. But it result only two. What is the mistake of my regex?

But i tried the same concept in perl this is works fine

```
 $s = "AAAKSKSAL( 1941 TO 1949 )( 3973 TO 3981 )  AAAKSKSAL";  
 @ar = $s=~m/([^\dTO\s\(\)]+)/g;  
 print @ar
```

Comment: `[]` specifies **single character**, not group. So `[^TO]` doesn't do what you think, it matches to **all** characters except `'T'` and `'O'`

Comment: Try: `var regex = /\(\s*\d+\s+TO\s+\d+\s*\)/g;`

Comment: @hindmost yes i dont want to match `T` or `O`.

Comment: What is the final result you are after?

Comment: @stribizhev For my first input data i want result `AAAKSKSAL`. Because of the only one matched pattern was found in my data.

Comment: @aja: You can do [`xa = xa.replace(/\s*\(\s*\d+\s+TO\s+\d+\s*\)\s*/ig, '');`](https://regex101.com/r/nM1xL9/1)

Comment: @anubhava This is works perfect. Can you post your answer i'll accept it.

Comment: I thought about [something like restricting your class to get only whole words](http://jsfiddle.net/pv2xxeot/) excluding specific ones, like `TO`, with a look-ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than match you should use `replace` and remove unwanted text:

```
xa = xa.replace(/\s*\(\s*\d+\s+TO\s+\d+\s*\)\s*/ig, '');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM1xL9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine but you're using *expression*.exec() incorrectly. Instead of this:

```
var matches =  [];
matches = regex.exec(xa); 
alert(matches);
```

Try this:

```
var matches = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(xa)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    matches.push(m[0]);
}

alert(matches);
```